# Image Lost on Minimizing Window

Tags: java, awt

I have added an image to a Canvas and then display that canvas on Panel. But when I minimize and then maximize the Window, the image disappears from the Panel. How can I solve this? Following is the code:

```
public class CloseCanvas extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        setSize(new Dimension(30,22));
        BufferedImage image = null;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/close.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a problem with AWT components being heavy-weight. Why don't you subclass JPanel instead and paint directly to the panel?

Comment: move setSize(new Dimension(30,22)); outside of paint method, read API because there are other methods how to set size for g.drawImage()

Comment: Many thanks. moving setSize outside the paint method solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This incorporates the advice of Fredrik and mKorbel, plus a few other tips unrelated to the immediate problem.

```
public class CloseCanvas extends Canvas{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;
    BufferedImage image = null;

    CloseCanvas() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/close.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,22));
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (image!=null) {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it better to use setPreferredSize() instead of setSize ?

Comment: Layout managers are more likely to honor the preferred (as well as maximum & minimum) size, than the size, of a component.  So short answer:  Yes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you move out the image loading from the paint method. It seems quite static and for every repaint of the Canvas the image will be reloaded which happens many, many times and that will happen on the event dispatch thread.